# How to revert search portlet configuration json for facets?

Tags: json, liferay

We had updated search portlet configuration facets configuration json with new facets.The purpose was to show documents and media files with a given set of file extension by adding the below json to the existing configuration json.
We referred the given link [Faceted search](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/faceted-search-and-customized-search-filtering) to add the below json:

`{
    "displayStyle": "asset_entries",
    "static": true,
    "weight": 1.5,
    "order": "OrderHitsDesc",
    "data": {
    "values": [
        "com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry"
    ],
    "frequencyThreshold": 0
    },
    "className": "com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.facet.AssetEntriesFacet",
    "label": "asset-type",
    "fieldName": "entryClassName"
},
{
    "displayStyle": "asset_entries",
    "static": true,
    "weight": 1.5,
    "order": "OrderHitsDesc",
    "data": {
    "values": ["bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "odg", "png", "svg"],
    "frequencyThreshold": 0
    },
    "className": "com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.facet.MultiValueFacet",
    "label": "images",
    "fieldName": "extension"
}`

which throws the below exception

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at 4141 [character 1 line 138]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:129)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:366)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:212)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:314)
```

Now accessing the search portlet configuration throws a blank page.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On analysing the source code,the file `configuration.jsp` in directory `portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\search`generates the configuration view.
The given code

```
JSONObject searchConfigurationJSONObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(searchConfiguration);
```

retrieves search config from

`String searchConfiguration = portletPreferences.getValue("searchConfiguration", StringPool.BLANK);`

Hence we had to manually update search configuration in DB in `portletpreferences`table to update the json with the missing `,`before the start of the added json.
Please suggest any other cleaner approach to solve this issue,if any.